# page blank after CURL url call

Tags: php, curl, sms

I am calling a CURL to send out SMS, which works fine. But after calling page goes blank and show like this. Below is my code and screen shot
[image]

Here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['btnAddProduct']))
{
    $msgUser = $_POST['txtSMS'];
$phone = "";
$fields_string = "";
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
   $phone .=$selected.",";
}
$phone = rtrim($phone,',');
$url = 'http://www.sms.com/PostSms.aspx';
$fields = array(
                    'userid' => urlencode('username'),
                    'pass' => urlencode('pwd'),
                    'phone' => urlencode($phone),
                    'msg' => urlencode($msgUser),
                    'title' => urlencode('code')
                );

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
//echo $fields_string;exit;
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
//$result = curl_exec($ch);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Message sent successfully");
        window.location ="sms.php";
    </script>
<?php 
}
```

Comment: I don't think browser can redirect when an alert is blocking. Also I noticed you commented the curl exec?

Comment: `CURLOPT_POST` only accepts `true|false|1|0`